# VK API. Как проверить, что пользователь оставил комментарий в обсуждении в группе?

Tags: php, api, вконтакте

Какой метод в VK API позволяет проверить, оставлял ли определенный пользователь комментарий к определенному обсуждению в группе?

Пользователь, соответственно, находится в той же группе, откуда работает API.

Answer (score 0):

Собсно ответ, если кому понадобится -

1)

```
$code = urlencode('return API.board.getComments(
        {
            "group_id":"АЙДИ_ГРУППЫ",
            "topic_id":"АЙДИ_ТОПИКА",
        });');
```

2. Шлем ее на `api.vk.com/method/execute?code=$code&v=<ВЕРСИЯ>&access_token=<ТОКЕН>`
3. Делаем `json_decode`
4. Записываем в переменную `$max` общее количество комментариев, а именно

`$max = $result->response->count;`

5. Пилим цикл и условие внутри него:

   ```
    $i = 0; 
    $count = 0;
    while ($i < $max){ 

        if ($result->response->items[$i]->from_id == $from_id) //Проверка, оставлял ли юзер комментарий
        {
            $text = $result->response->items[$i]->text; //Сам комментарий
            $count++; // =1, значит оставлял.
            break;

        }
        $i++;

    }
   ```

Где `$from_id` - айди юзера, которого проверяем.

6. По нужде выводим нужный результат в файл.